# Plot one point on Highcharts JS graph according to x-axis?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

Here is an image of my graph:

[image]

It is meant to show the user that it ends/drops off at a specific age according to their current age.

Here is my code declaring the highchart:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Graph'
    },
    xAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        max: 100,
        title: {
            text: 'Age'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        max: 1000000,
        title: {
            text: 'Amount'
        },
        tickInterval: 1000000
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'Amount is <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b> at age {point.x}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            pointStart: 44,
            marker: {
                enabled: true,
                symbol: 'circle',
                radius: 2,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Amount',
        data: [1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000,
        1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000,
        1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, null, null, null, null,
        null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
        null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ]
    }]
});
```

My question is, how can I plot one random point on the graph that will always be greater than, or equal to the last number on the x-axis (age)?  This point needs to stand out (visibly) and have unique text in the hover over (the text being the value I provide).

I've searched through the documentation for a bit and haven't seen anything that gives me the option to do this.

Is there anyway to do this easily?  If no, any hacks to give this effect, or is it even possible?

Comment: Its not clear to me what you are trying to do.  Do you just want another series that has 1 data point in it?  Or is it something more complex? http://jsfiddle.net/blaird/b1o3t21b/1/

Comment: Put it in an answer so I can accept -- it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you add another series with a data point:
http://jsfiddle.net/blaird/b1o3t21b/1/

```
, {
        type:'scatter',
        name: 'Some Point',
               marker: {
            symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)',
            width: 16,
            height: 16
        },
        data: [{
            x: 85,
            y: 500000
        }]
    }
```